How to PATCH assets content in DV360 creatives?
I was trying to update the asset content in specific creative through the API.
Note that updateMask = assets and here's the full JSON request:
{
  "assets": [
    {
      "asset": {
        "content": "image url"
       
      },
      "role": "ASSET_ROLE_MAIN"
    },
    {
      "asset": {
        "content": "/sadbundle/423432123/asset__2_.jpg"
       
      }
     
    },
    {
      "asset": {
        "content": "/sadbundle/423432123/asset__3_.jpg"
       
      }
     
    },
    {
      "asset": {
        "content": "/sadbundle/423432123/asset__4_.jpg"
       
      }
     
    },
    {
      "asset": {
        "content": "/sadbundle/423432123/next_button.png"
       
      }
     
    },
    {
      "asset": {
        "content": "/sadbundle/423432123/previous_button.png"
       
      }
     
    }
   
  ]
 
}

But it keeps giving me this error:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INTERNAL_ERROR: Internal Error",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}

I tried to send this request with different URLs and also added a role for all of the assets but it seems that the issue still happening I'd really appreciate any help about this.
